# Why does decrypting modified AES-CBC ciphertext fail decryption?

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes, aes-gcm

I am trying to get familiar with encryption/decryption. I am using deno as it supports the web crypto API.

I can encrypt and decrypt to get back the original plaintext using AES-CBC.

What I am now doing now is to encrypt, then manually modify the ciphertext and then decrypt. My expectation is that this would still work since I understand that AES-CBC does not provide integrity and authenticity check. (AES-GCM is the one that is AEAD)

But when I modify the cipher text and try to decrypt, it fails with the following error:

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) OperationError: Decryption failed
let deCryptedPlaintext = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(param, key, asByteArray);
                         ^
    at async SubtleCrypto.decrypt (deno:ext/crypto/00_crypto.js:598:29)
    at async file:///Users/me/delete/run.js:33:26
```

Does AES-CBC also have integrity checks? Or why is the decryption failing?

Comment: In a block cipher mode like CBC, a corrupt ciphertext leads with a certain probability to a corrupt padding (WebCrypto uses PKCS#7 padding). In case of a corrupt padding, WebCrypto displays an error message. However note, that a missing error message is no guarantee that the ciphertext is not corrupt, since a valid padding can also result by chance.

Comment: In other words, AES-CBC with PKCS#7 padding *does* provide some degree of integrity check, but the quality of that check is so poor that cryptographers refuse to label it as such.

Comment: @Topaco you wanna write your comment up as an answer to it can be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

In Deno I had a similar issue while encrypting a jwt around server and client and could not rely on the `TextDecoder` class for the same reason:

> error: OperationError: Decryption failed

After some hours I played around and found a solution, a bit tricky, but is doing the job right:

```js
(async ()=> {
    const textEncoder = new TextEncoder();
    const textDecoder = new TextDecoder();
    
    const rawKey = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
    
    //  we import the key that we have previously generated 
    const cryptoKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw",
        rawKey,
        "AES-CBC",
        true,
        ["encrypt", "decrypt"],
    );
    
    // we generate the IV
    const iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
    
    // here is the string we want to encrypt
    const stringToEncrypt = "foobar"
    
    // we encrypt
    const encryptedString = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        { name: "AES-CBC", iv: iv },
        cryptoKey,
        textEncoder.encode(stringToEncrypt),
    );
    
    // we transform the encrypted string to an UInt8Array
    const uint8ArrayEncryptedString = new Uint8Array(encryptedString);
    
    // we transform the Array to a String so we have a representation we can carry around
    const stringifiedEncryption = 
    String.fromCharCode(...uint8ArrayEncryptedString);
    
    /* now is time to decrypt again the message, so we transform the string into 
     a char array and for every iteration we transform 
     the char into a byte, so in the end we have a byte array
    */
    const stringByteArray = 
    [...stringifiedEncryption].map((v) => v.charCodeAt(0))
    
    // we transform the byte array into a Uint8Array buffer
    const stringBuffer = new Uint8Array(stringByteArray.length);
    
    // we load the buffer
    stringByteArray.forEach((v, i) => stringBuffer[i] = v)
    
    // we decrypt again
    const againDecrString = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
        { name: "AES-CBC", iv: iv },
        cryptoKey,
        stringBuffer,
    );
    
    console.log(textDecoder.decode(againDecrString))
})()
```

For some of you relying on the class for the same purpose, I suggest you to use this solution. The underlying implementation pheraps loses some information while converting back and forth the string (I needed it as string after the encryption) and so the decryption fails.